# Создание объекта без ключевого слова new

Tags: java, классы, объекты

Если в Java для выделения памяти под новый объект используют ключевое слово `new`, то почему в данной ситуации, при создании экземпляра класса `public final class DateTimeFormatter` оно упускается?

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: Это вообще-то вызов статического метода, а не определение объекта. И не обязательно может быть определен в конкретном методе, он может быть проинициализирован за много ранее, чем в конкретном методе для вызова, не исключая также и блок `static{...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что слово (оператор) `new` находится внутри статического метода `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-